# Why does an LED remain glowing when MOSFET gate is open?

Tags: led, mosfet, floating

[image: LED MOSFET Circuit]

Hello,

I'm working with an N-Channel MOSFET (Link to data sheet for the MOSFET - https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FQU13N10L-D.pdf) for the first time on a DC motor project, and I'm trying to familiarize myself with it using a basic LED circuit. The code is just basic LED blink:

```
Gate_Pin_Write(1);
Delay(500);
Gate_Pin_Write(0);
Delay(2000);
```

When the Gate pin writes zero, the LED is still glowing dimly, not completely off like I'd expect. I hooked up my DC motor and it works as expected with the motor starting and stopping based on the pin output signal, but I can't get it to work as expected with the LED. I connected my multimeter to do a continuity test between drain and source and it is only reading continuity when the gate pin is high and the LED is shining brightly.

Also, when I pull the source wire (connecting Source to Ground) the LED is still dimly lighting up when the gate pin is high, but not producing any visible light when the gate pin is low. Is there a floating voltage when the gate pin is open that I'm not accounting for? I've tried to place a resistor in a few spots, but with no luck. I'd appreciate any guidance.

Edit:

I still have been unable to figure out the issue and was concerned it may have something to do with the PSOC5 I was using, so I switched to a basic Arduino and rebuilt the circuit on a breadboard with the schematic shown in the original post **minus the 1kOhm resistor connected to the GPIO** and nothing else on the breadboard, but the issue persists and the LED is still glowing when the GPIO is low. I've taken the following readings:

Vdd to Ground: 4.9 V

Voltage across LED:
High - 3.47 V
Low  - 2.33 V

Gate(+) to Ground(-):
High - 4.21 V
Low  - 33.2 mV

Gate(+) to Source(-):
High - 4.21 V
Low  - 33.2 mV

Gate(+) to Drain(-):
High - 4.20 V
Low  - **-**2.27 V

Drain(+) to Source(-):
High - 2.30 V
Low  - 4.0 mV

Also, I put my meter in Diode mode and tested drain to source:

Source(+) to Drain(-): 0.53 V

Drain(+) to Source(-): 1.41 V

After watching some videos, I'm concerned about that second reading because I can't get it to go to zero. I think this may just be a bad MOSFET and want to pick up a new one to try out.

Edit2: I picked up a new N-channel MOSFET and the circuit works exactly as expected. I guess the gate on the original one was somehow remaining partially closed at all times. Thanks everyone who offered suggestions

Comment: Can you measure voltage from gate to source while a "0" is written to the pin? Some LEDs are very sensitive, and will glow a little with mere microamperes of current.

Comment: Did you measure the voltage with a multi meter to verify it is changing?

Comment: There is another leakage path to ground that you didn't realize was there. Could be a small leakage current through the mosfet. Or it could be leakage through some other circuit which you have not shown.

Comment: In the circuit you show in the question, R1 is "perfectly in series" with the LED. There is nothing else connected there. So you can measure the voltage across R1 to see how much leakage current is actually flowing. (V = IR... solve for I).

Comment: @rdtsc Gate to Source voltage measures 1.07V while low and 1.80V while high. I'm looking at my diagram but not sure what this measurement means exactly.

Comment: @mkeith the voltage across the LED changing from 3.5V (high) to 2.2V (low) so it's still drawing 10mA when low

Comment: 1.07 is too high of a gate voltage. Something is wrong. 1.8V is not high enough, so there is definitely something fishy about your gate voltages. Start with that, I guess.

Comment: I removed the jumper commanding the gate and the LED remains lit with 2.6V across it. There's no other path to ground except through the MOSFET and source. Could this just be a faulty component? I'm not sure if an uncommanded gate is in an ambiguous state or should be open

Comment: Those readings are neither particularly high or low.  Perhaps you should consider a MOSFET driver.  They take a lot of complication out of using a weak output pin to drive a large MOSFET.  
Can you measure the high and low voltage without the MOSFET connected?

Comment: Did you connect the ground from the arduino to the ground of the MOSFET/LED circuit?

Comment: The fact that you have a Vgs = 1.07 V when it should be (close to) 0 V (zero volts) means you have an error in your circuit. Draw the complete circuit including all the **ground** connections that you did not show in your schematic.

Comment: Just to be clear, for the OP, until the gate voltage can be controlled from near 0V to near VCC, there is no point in worrying about anything else. Start with that. You need to fix that. Maybe disconnect the FET altogether and just focus on getting the IO pin to swing over its full range (0 to VCC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MOSFET might be **leaking** a small amount of current which is enough to make a small LED glow a little.

The MOSFET you're using is rated for 10 Amperes which is overkill for a small LED. If you used this MOSFET to switch a 5 A lightbulb on/off you would not notice the leakage current.

One solutions is to use a MOSFET more suitable to small currents, for example a [2N7000](https://datasheet.octopart.com/2N7000-ON-Semiconductor-datasheet-98551285.pdf) or an [AO3400](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/ao3400.pdf).

Another (easier) solution is to give that leakage current a way **around the LED**, that can be done by placing a **resistor in parallel with the LED**. Try a 10 kohm resistor. If that doesn't work, try a lower value like 1 kohm.

With that resistor in place the MOSFET's leakage current will flow through the resistor and that should prevent it from flowing through the LED so the LED should not glow anymore.

Comment: Red LED's in particular are able to glow faintly with surprisingly small currents.

Comment: OP mentioned that this is a DC motor project. Of course, OP also omitted any motor in the schematic. But I guess in the real circuit there is a motor being powered by the FET.

Comment: @mkeith Then if there was a motor also being powered from the same LED, then the LED would not light up. Maybe OP has connected the LED but not the motor (yet) and sees the LED glow. When the motor is connected, that will resolve by itself. Vgs = 1.07 V when off is also weird. There's obviously a mistake somewhere.

Comment: There is no motor attached in this circuit. The main project is a DC motor one, but I built this specific circuit just to test the MOSFET. The MCU is providing VDD and ground to a breadboard and the only other wire from the MCU is the GPIO to the gate. The rest of the components on the breadboard are as seen in the schematic

Comment: I chose your answer since you were correct the MOSFET was leaking current and I did need to switch to a new one! The original seems to be compromised in some way

Comment: Oh, maybe the gate "blew out" on the previous mosfet. So the gpio pin had a hard time driving high and low.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you did not connect the ground of your microcontroller (Arduino?) to the ground of the MOSFET circuit. Make sure you have a solid connection between the two, and then measure the MOSFET gate voltage **with respect to ground** when the output is both 0 and 1.

Comment: I measured voltage Gate to Ground as well as Gate to Source and got the same readings: 1.8 while high and 1.07 while low. I plugged the source to ground connection into another MCU ground pin to verify as well (PSOC5)

Comment: Did you explicitly configure the GPIO pin as an **output**?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the batteries in your multimeter and check the gate-source voltage again. Set the pin low; should see 0.0 to about 0.5v. Set the pin high; should see Vdd to Vdd-0.5v.

If you still get the same readings, measure from the PSoC ground to GPIO pin. If you STILL get the same readings, then the GPIO is unable to power the pin properly for some reason.

The [CY8C52 Programmable System-On-Chip (PSoC 5)](https://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/cypress/psoc5/cy8c52_ds.pdf) datasheet states that it will run from 2.7V to 5.5V, and notes *"All GPIOs configurable as open drain high/low, pull up/down, High-Z, or strong output"*.  Ensure that GPIO is set to *strong output*.

Section 6.4: *"There are two types of I/O pins on every device; those with USB provide a third type. Both General Purpose I/O (GPIO) and Special I/O (SIO) provide similar digital functionality. The primary differences are their analog capability and drive strength."*